# Creating an Indexvariable in R based on several Indexvariables

Tags: r, variables, spss

I'm looking for a fast and easy alternative in R to create new Indexvariables out of several existing Indexvariables. Eg:

```
var1 var2 var3 newvar
0    1    1    1
0    0    0    0
1    0    0    1
1    1    1    1
1    0    9    1
1    9    9    1
0    9    9    1
```

How  to create the newvar column with only one line in R?
I have also the value 9 for "not answered" in the dataframe. I Just want to count the values 1 (and nothing else).

I'm looking for an alternative for the SPSS-Code:

```
COMPUTE newvar= any(1,var1,var2,var3).
```

Comment: Anything you've already tried? Why did that not work? SO is not a code-writing service.

Comment: `dat$newvar <- apply(dat, 1, any)` could do. Do you want that?

Comment: I tried this: 
    df<-cbind.data.frame(var1,var2,var3)
    ivar <- sapply(1,function(x)rowSums(df==x))

Comment: or: `df$newvar <- +(rowSums(df>0)>0)`

Comment: rowSums sums up. Because I have also the value 9 for "not answered" in the data.frame it is not helpful. I Just want to count the values 1 (and nothing else.

Comment: then `df$newvar <-  rowSums(df==1)`

Comment: @VolkerHolzendorf nobody here can read your mind you know. Add this information to the question, not in the comments.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R find value in multiple data frame columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17288222/r-find-value-in-multiple-data-frame-columns). Coercion of logical to integer is (should be) trivial.

Answer (score 1):

To count the values `1` for each row you can just use:

```
mydf$newvar <- rowSums(mydf==1)
```

If you want to see whether any of the values is `1` (as your intended outpur `newvar` implies):

```
mydf$newvar <- +(rowSums(mydf==1)>0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Henrik!
You are right. It was answered in the thread you mentioned.
Here the answer again, because nothing is trivial for everyone :-)

```
newvar<-as.numeric(apply(cbind(var1,var2,var3), 1, function(r) any(r == 1)))
```

Elch von Oslo